# what is the internal folder to save files or pictures on android when there is no SDCard present

Tags: android, path, directory, android-sdcard

When an SDCARD is present and I take a picture with my app, I can save it to:

```
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
```

I want to achieve the same, but for internal storage.
Is there an internal directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very same path in code. When there's no external storage, it will refer to the internal one (the one your system settings is configured as "default storage").

Comment: Great thanks.  What about if I want to FORCE to save to the internal storage? any way to get that path ?

Comment: Not that I am aware. I think it ALWAYS uses the card which is set as primary.